# how to measure Kinect Skeleton Axis dimension?

Tags: c#, windows, kinect, gesture-recognition, skeleton-code

I am developing a kinect gesture application . So i got a code from internet to hand up gesture .

```
handupgesture()
{

 bool up = false;
 float refDistance = 0.2F;

 SkeletonPoint refPos = localSkeletonHistory[0].Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].Position;
 SkeletonPoint startPos = localSkeletonHistory[0].Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position;

 for (int i = 20; i < localSkeletonHistory.Count; i++)
 {
           if (!(Math.Abs(localSkeletonHistory[i].Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].Position.Y - refPos.Y) < 0.05F &&
                   Math.Abs(localSkeletonHistory[i].Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.X - startPos.X) < 0.05F &&
                   Math.Abs(localSkeletonHistory[i].Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Z - startPos.Z) < 0.05F ))
            {
                break;
            }
            if (localSkeletonHistory[i].Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y >= (startPos.Y + refDistance))
            {
                up = true;
                SkeletonHistory.Clear();
                break;
            }
        }
        return up;
}
```

my doubts are :

- What is **0.05F** ? is it in meter ? centimetre ?
- Z axis distance means distance of joint from kinect distance . is it ?

This code is not detecting hand up . Any mistakes or suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

`0.05F` in `C#` means a float number.

> The float keyword signifies a simple type that stores 32-bit
>   floating-point values. The following table shows the precision and
>   approximate range for the float type.
>
> By default, a real numeric literal on the right side of the assignment
>   operator is treated as double. Therefore, to initialize a float
>   variable, use the suffix f or F, as in the following example:

```
float x = 3.5F; or in your case 0.05F
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx

As for your second question , z-axes represents the depth.
Each frame, the depth image captured is processed by the Kinect runtime into skeleton data. Skeleton data contains 3D position data for human skeletons for up to two people who are visible in the depth sensor. The position of a skeleton and each of the skeleton joints (if active tracking is enabled) are stored as (x, y, z) coordinates. Unlike depth space, skeleton space coordinates are expressed in meters.

The x, y, and z-axes are the body axes of the depth sensor as shown below:

[image: Skeleton space]

This is a right-handed coordinate system that places a Kinect at the origin with the positive z-axis extending in the direction in which the Kinect is pointed. The positive y-axis extends upward, and the positive x-axis extends to the left.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx

As for your last question - try to reduce the 0.5F tolerance.

In addition, I would like to point you for some examples in Windows Kinect site:
https://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/